# Nesting items in a container using haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to use an if statement to determine if items fall inside the same html container or get a new one. I can't seem to get more than one item inside the same container using haml because of the way it handles nesting.

Example:

```
%div.line.boards.main_boards
  - @boards.each_with_index do |board, index|
    - @board = board
    -if index == 0
      %div.unit.size1of5
    -if index <= 1
      = render :partial => "board_projects"
    -if index == 2
      %div.unit.size4of5
        = render :partial => "board_projects"
```

In this example the element %div.unit.size1of5 should wrap around both items index 0 & 1. However it places them after the div closes. If I indent the code where the partial is rendered so it's nested inside the div it only pulls in the index 0 item.

How is this accomplished in haml?

Comment: If index 0 and 1 render the same things, you don't need the first conditional, right?  It's not a nesting issue, but rather you're only outputting the div when the index is 0.

Comment: This is a nightmare of conditionals :)... What are your trying to obtain?.

Comment: Shooting on the dark you can try to move your `index == 0` condition block into the `index <= 1` condition block.

Comment: Can you give an example of html you want to get, and what you’re currently getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters into the class of a div like so:

```
.unit{:class => "size#{index}"}
  = render :partial => "board_projects"
```

And then make it a CSS problem instead of a Ruby/HAML one.